# How to populate existing data in a form using jquery or ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a data like this:

```
    Tape-ID Video Type  Date Created          Director  Camera Man  Editor  Reporter    Tag
  12-12-12  Documentary January 01, 2013    Sachit  Helloy              He  water, water pollution, boudha
```

When the user checks on Edit button the form will display. I want the existing data to be written in a form so that user can just change the required fields.
How it can be done in Ajax or jquery? I am using django 1.5.

Comment: this is unclear and incomplete. this question is asking how you would receive data from your server via ajax? where is this data that you have to populate the fields? is it persisted in a database or do you have it stored in the user's cache?

Comment: The data is stored in the database. But the data are already populated in the template. When the user selects the data I want to show the data in the edit data form. I am asking is it possible to populate data from template to the edit form itself without going to the backend again.

Comment: as long as the data exists in memory somewhere on the client side when you want to achieve this then it is possible. do you have a code example of what you've tried?

Comment: The data is already there in the client side. I just want to post the data of user checked row to the edit form.

Comment: "I just want to post the data of user checked row to the edit form." you want to post the data back to the database once they have finished updating it? that would make sense but otherwise im not sure wat you mean in this context using the word post

Comment: By post I meant show. Yes, I will update the data once they have finished updating it. I can do it.

Comment: ok well provide some code and u'll get an answer